# Is there a way to add a tuple of position as an attribute to a created node in networkx?

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, graph, networkx

I'm trying to get the position of all the nodes that are being made into my graph. The current goal is to create all the nodes which possess an `x` and `y` coordinate.

What I was reading is about attributes when using `add_nodes_from()` and possibly create a position attribute for my nodes. Reading a little bit of documentation and another StackOverflow is unsuccessful for me.

ex.txt file:

```
a2a 5 0
##start
a0 1 2
##end
a1 9 2
3 5 4
```

python file:

```
import re
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def file_parsing(file_path):
    cnt = 0
    output_list = []

    with open(file_path, 'r') as fp:
        for line in fp:
            cnt += 1
            #checks for the room name and coordinates
            if re.match('([^\s#]{1,10}) (\d+) (\d+)', line, re.MULTILINE):
                output_list.append(line.strip().split(' '))
            #checks for start
            if line.startswith('##start'):
                output_list.append(next(fp, '').strip().split())
            #checks for start
            if line.startswith('##end'):
                output_list.append(next(fp, '').strip().split())
    room_name = [item[0] for item in output_list]
    x_coord = [int(item[1]) for item in output_list]
    y_coord = [int(item[2]) for item in output_list]
    x_y = list(zip(x_coord, y_coord))
    return (room_name, output_list, x_y)

rooms, room_coords, xpos_ypos = file_parsing('ex.txt')
print("Room information: ", room_coords)
print("X and Y position as tuple list: ", xpos_ypos)
DG = nx.DiGraph()
DG.add_nodes_from(rooms, pos = xpos_ypos)
pos = nx.get_node_attributes(DG, 'pos')
print(pos)

plt.figure()

nx.draw_networkx(DG)
```

As you see, I have my `xpos_ypos` in a zip, which creates a list of tuples. And my order of iteration matters because the first room will have the x and y coordinates from the first tuple.

For example, my first room is `a2a` which will have the coordinate of `(5, 0)`. Room `a0` will have coordinates if `(1, 2)`. Now, if I want to do the same thing over and over for each room: how could I add the room coordinates attributes to each room? In my case, I'm getting a dictionary as a result:

`{'a2a': [(5, 0), (1, 2), (9, 2), (5, 4)], 'a0': [(5, 0), (1, 2), (9, 2), (5, 4)], 'a1': [(5, 0), (1, 2), (9, 2), (5, 4)], '3': [(5, 0), (1, 2), (9, 2), (5, 4)]}`

and this is the output `draw_networkx(DG)`:
[image: digraph]

Comment: nx.draw takes an argument pos - try : nx.draw_networkx(DG,pos=pos)

Comment: I tried it already before and I'm getting an error saying `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)` @JohannesWachs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not working because you are passing the positions incorrectly.
I have made a few changes to your function so that it returns a dictionary with keys as the node names and values as `[x, y]` co-ordinates. Something like this

```
{'a2a': (5, 0), 'a0': (1, 2), 'a1': (9, 2), '3': (5, 4)}
```

Then I created the graph from the returned dictionary and the above dictionary to the `pos` attribute of `nx.draw_networkx` function.

```
import re
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
def file_parsing(file_path):
    cnt = 0
    output_list = []

    with open(file_path, 'r') as fp:
        for line in fp:
            cnt += 1
            #checks for the room name and coordinates
            if re.match('([^\s#]{1,10}) (\d+) (\d+)', line, re.MULTILINE):
                output_list.append(line.strip().split(' '))
            #checks for start
            if line.startswith('##start'):
                output_list.append(next(fp, '').strip().split())
            #checks for start
            if line.startswith('##end'):
                output_list.append(next(fp, '').strip().split())
    room_name = [item[0] for item in output_list]
    x_coord = [int(item[1]) for item in output_list]
    y_coord = [int(item[2]) for item in output_list]
    x_y = list(zip(x_coord, y_coord))

    #--------------Changes start from here -----------#

    pos_dict = dict(zip(room_name, x_y))
    return pos_dict

room_pos_dict = file_parsing('ex.txt')
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(room_pos_dict.keys())
nx.set_node_attributes(G, room_pos_dict, 'pos')
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'pos'))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have been trying to connect the nodes together by using the `add_edges_from()` from node to node with their position with yours. I tried separately with the code I have already without positioning the nodes yet and no luck yet.  For example, my nome `a0` needs to connect with `3` and `a2a` nodes. In your example, how would I manage in connecting nodes together with the dictionary that is created already?

Comment: Your welcome! Can you please create a seperate question as your original question was just for the original positioning of nodes and this answer solves that :) Also, if this answer helped you out can you please mark it as the correct one. In your new question, also mention about how to read the edges from the file that you have, i.e. `ex.txt`.