# How to add multiple edges from multiple nodes that are already created with networkx?

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, graph, networkx

When I create a dictionary of nodes with their coordinates tuples, how can I add the edges from a node to node and keep the graph stable without anything moving around?

I was looking around for other solutions around the documentation of networkx and Googling too. What I found out is using a function `add_edges_from()` function, which creates a path from a node to a node. However, when doing this, this won't be in the correct coordinates and will be basically moving around. I made a post in StackOverflow ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55427052/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-tuple-of-position-as-an-attribute-to-a-created-node-in-n)) to use the coordinates of the node and draw the graph. This is what I wanted, but now my tradeoff is that I'm losing my edges. In my `ex.txt`, I'm parsing my nodes and the coordinates of it. After parsing my nodes and coordinates, then I'm looking from which node has an edge to another node.

ex.txt file:

```
3
a2a 5 0
##start
a0 1 2
##end
a1 9 2
3 5 4
a0-a2a
a0-3
a2a-1
3-1
a2a-3
```

python file:

```
import re
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
def file_parsing(file_path):
    cnt = 0
    output_list = []

    with open(file_path, 'r') as fp:
        for line in fp:
            cnt += 1
            #checks for the room name and coordinates
            if re.match('([^\s#]{1,10}) (\d+) (\d+)', line, re.MULTILINE):
                output_list.append(line.strip().split(' '))
            #checks for start
            if line.startswith('##start'):
                output_list.append(next(fp, '').strip().split())
            #checks for start
            if line.startswith('##end'):
                output_list.append(next(fp, '').strip().split())
    room_name = [item[0] for item in output_list]
    x_coord = [int(item[1]) for item in output_list]
    y_coord = [int(item[2]) for item in output_list]
    x_y = list(zip(x_coord, y_coord))
    pos_dict = dict(zip(room_name, x_y))
    return pos_dict

room_pos_dict = file_parsing('ex.txt')
print(room_pos_dict)
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(room_pos_dict.keys())
nx.set_node_attributes(G, room_pos_dict, 'pos')
# nx.set_edge_attributes(G, room_pos_dict.values(), 'pos')
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'pos'))
```

This would the ideal graph I made out:
[image: edges digraph]

But now, they are randomly placed everywhere.

Now, from my previous post I made (thank you Mohammed Kashif), I get the position of all my nodes, but not the edges:

[image: positioned nodes]

My expected is a combination of both: nodes with their position and the edges connected to each node.

Please bear with me, I'm trying to learn Python and networkx :). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**
Assuming the contents of `ex.txt` are :

```
3
a2a 5 0
##start
a0 1 2
##end
a1 9 2
3 5 4
a0-a2a
a0-3
a2a-a1
3-a1
a2a-3
```

So after a few changes to your code, here is the final result. I have added comments in the code to help you understand what has been changed

```
import re
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

def file_parsing(file_path):
    cnt = 0
    output_list = []
    edge_list = []
    with open(file_path, 'r') as fp:
        for line in fp:
            cnt += 1
            #checks for the room name and coordinates
            if re.match('([^\s#]{1,10}) (\d+) (\d+)', line, re.MULTILINE):
                output_list.append(line.strip().split(' '))
            #checks for start
            if line.startswith('##start'):
                output_list.append(next(fp, '').strip().split())
            #checks for start
            if line.startswith('##end'):
                output_list.append(next(fp, '').strip().split())

            # --------- Check for edges -----------#
            if '-' in line:
                src, dest = line.split('-')
                edge_list.append([src.strip(), dest.strip()])
    room_name = [item[0] for item in output_list]
    x_coord = [int(item[1]) for item in output_list]
    y_coord = [int(item[2]) for item in output_list]
    x_y = list(zip(x_coord, y_coord))
    pos_dict = dict(zip(room_name, x_y))

    return pos_dict, edge_list

room_pos_dict, edge_list = file_parsing('ex.txt')

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_nodes_from(room_pos_dict.keys())

#----------- Add edges from the edge list ------ 
G.add_edges_from(edge_list)

nx.set_node_attributes(G, room_pos_dict, 'pos')
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'pos'))
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, I forgot to change the link names. I edited out the link usage. The name of the nodes are strictly names, therefore they are strings (e.g '0', '1', '2', '1234abcd' are strings, not ints). The edge `a0-a2a` is a directed path from `a0` to `a2a` if that makes sense.